# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes' on Jupyter notebook only

Tags: python, json, utf-8, jupyter

The very same code

```
A=b'["c1006","c1007"]'
json.loads(A)
```

works in Python console, but doesn't work in Jupyter notebook, saying

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Why and how to fix / write portable?

---

I am using Python 3.x on Linux:

```
(py36) dims@calculon:~$ python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> A= b'["c1006","c1007"]'
>>> json.loads(A)
['c1006', 'c1007']
```

Comment: You are almost certainly using Python 2 in the console and Python 3 in your notebook. Writing Python 2/ 3 compatible code is not trivial. it is best to think of them as different languages.

Comment: It's apparently about the minor version here, thus your Jupyter notebook is probably pre-3.6. The [docs for `json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) say: "*Changed in version 3.6: s can now be of type bytes or bytearray.*"

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
The version of the notebook server is: 5.6.0
The server is running on this version of Python:
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

---

```
A=b'["c1006","c1007"]'
json.loads(A)
```

> ['c1006', 'c1007']

Check your version,seems to be running different python version than your anaconda has :

```
import sys 
sys.version
```